# Otto not sending data When Activity ReCreates (After OnDestroy)?

Tags: android, service, otto

I am using [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) to send `events` from `IntentService` to my Activity. `IntentService` is **Downloading** files from server and send progress to Activity this is working with `otto` very well.
 -

### I have done so far

1. registered otto in `OnResume`

   ```
   BusStation.getBus().unregister(this);
   ```
2. created function to receive events

`@Subscribe
    public void receiveProgress(Message message){
        Log.i("Downloader",message.getMessage()+"");
    }`

3. unregister bus in `OnPause`

   `BusStation.getBus().unregister(this);`
4. I have `Button` on which click DownloadService is started and this service sends download progress to `receiveProgress` function.

but when I close my app and Restart app and then if `DownloadSerice` still downloading file it never send Download progress event on `receiveProgress`
so how to relink this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `BusStation.getBus()` returns a singleton. However, when you restart the app the singleton has to be created again and therefore it is not the same instance anymore.

You can solve this problem by using LocalBroadcastManager instead:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html